# How to convert HTML coordinates into PDF coordinates(pdf-lib, javaScript)

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe

what I need to do is dragging png image to some coordinates and inserting this image into PDF document using pdf-lib. But I've found out that the pdf coordinates are not the same as the HTML coordinates. Is there a way to convert HTML mouse coordinates into PDF coordinates ? I'm rendering this PDF using iframe.

Thanks in advance for any helpful information.

Comment: Please make this a [mcve] by including the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem

Comment: But that's the problem. I do not have a code because I don't know how the algorithm should look like.

Comment: What do you currently have?

Comment: I have implemented pdf loading, png loading, png moving according to a mouse coordinates and now I want to insert that image on the coordinates but when I try to do so it just goes with an dynamic offset(when I position Image closer to right site the inserted image is even more to the right site and the same is true for left site)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I got the answer now for anyone who will need this in the future:
in pdf-lib there are used points instead of pixels. Points are mostly 72dpi and that is almost 1 inch. Pixels are 0.75 times bigger(actually smaller but bigger because of multiply) than 72dpi so what you need to do is multiply mouse coordinates(or whatever) by 0.75. Then you need to adjust the offset and you are good to go! Hope someone find this useful.